# How to serialize list of custom objects for instance state in Xamarin for Android?

Tags: android, xamarin, instancestate

I've got a generic list as data source for my activity. Now I want to save this list in instance state.

In native Android applications this can be done very easily - I just let my custom model implement Serializable - as the generic ArrayList implements Serializable too, I can simply use

```
bundle.putSerializable(myList)
```

to save it to instance state.

The List<T> in Xamarin doesn't implement Java.IO.ISerializable. So how to put my list in instance state here?

Any ideas how to do this in Xamarin for Android?

Crosspost from https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/57637/how-to-serialize-list-of-custom-objects-for-instance-state

Comment: I usually just serialize myself using 'JsonConvert.(De)SerializeObject<T>' from Json.Net.

Comment: That's of course a solution - I thought there's something built in.

Comment: There is also XmlSerializer out of the box.